# Refresh rate gone missing, Nothing seems to fix it!

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I had a computer running a projector at 239.79hz fresh rate for a months.
One day the 239.79 (240hz) refresh-rate is no longer available.

Changed GFX card in the computer and it does NOT WORK.

Changed power-supply in the computer and it does NOT WORK.

Tried another computer with same projector and cable and it WORKS just fine.

Totally deleted the hard-drive with bios SSD delete and re-installed Ubuntu and it does NOT WORK.

Tried another projector and cable that I know works, and it does NOT WORK on that particular computer.

WHERE in the world can it store this info????

BIOS?

Tried Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, Xubuntu 20.04, 23.04
No luck at all.
NVIDIA 3080TI and NVIDIA 4070TI with various different drivers tested.

I am going crazy over this.